# How to make a reset form button without type 'markup'?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

**My situation:**

I built a form with FAPI. I display the results in a table like this:

```
function grap_contact_repository_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  ...
  $form_state['results_table'] = array('#markup' => grap_contact_repository($matches));
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

The `grap_contact_repository` function returns a theme_table.

**My problem:**

Because of the results_table that already uses a `#markup` type, I can't build a reset button for my form using `'#type' => 'markup'` too. (Because all the results table will be clickable too).

I'm looking for an alternative to make this button work. I tried this:

```
$form['clear'] = array(
  '#type'       => 'button',
  '#value'      => 'Réinitialiser',
  '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'this.form.reset();'),
);
```

or this: (http://www.blue-bag.com/blog/drupal-form-api-reset-button)

```
  $form['reset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#button_type' => 'reset',
    '#value' => 'Réinitialiser',
    '#validate' => array(),
    '#attributes' => array(
      'onclick' => 'this.form.reset(); return false;',
    ),
  );
```

But it doesn't work. The onclick works if I put another JavaScript like `alert`. I have nothing in my JS errors console.

Does someone have an idea to make it work?

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had to do this in jQuery as I thought. But if I want all the form to be reset, means all the fields values to "", the `.reset()` method isn't enough. I had to set all the values to "" and empty my results table manually like this:

```
$form['reset'] = array(
'#type' => 'button',
'#button_type' => 'reset',
'#value' => 'Réinitialiser',
'#validate' => array(),
'#attributes' => array(
  'onclick' => 'jQuery("#edit-categories, #edit-contextes, #edit-organismes, #edit-fonctions").val(""); 
                jQuery(".history-results tr").remove();',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Type should be reset, not button.
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

You right, there is no such type. I was able to get this working with 2 submit buttons and return false (similar to your original implementation).

```
function drupalform_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['name']=array(
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#title'=>t('Enter your name'),
    '#description'=>t('Your first name goes here')
    );

  $form['submit_button1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    );  

  $form['reset_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',    
    '#value' => 'Reset',
    '#validate' => array(),
    '#attributes' => array(
        'onclick' => 'this.form.reset(); return false;',
        ),
      );

  return $form;
}
```

If it still doesn't work there is this alternative solution: [How to reset specific form elements](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82092/how-to-reset-specific-form-elements?rq=1)

Comment: No. Do you see any "reset" in #type attribute? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#type